# JasperReports club union result into a single row

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, union, ireport, crosstab

I have a Union of two queries in a report using crosstab.
The purpose of the reports is to list the values corresponding to each date.

1st Query returns the values corresponding to a date.
2nd Query returns the remaining dates and their values.

Finally, Union of both the queries is done.
Many people might suggest to achieve this using a single query but I have been unable to do this with a single query using LEFT JOIN as it does not return the NULL values.
Even if I get that working, the GROUP BY clause that I have will separate into two rows in iReport.. NON NULLS AND NULLS.

So, the only way I can think of doing this is using a Union.
The output looks like

```
      01/01/2013 02/01/2013 03/01/2013 04/01/2013 05/01/2013
X     £120.00    £120.00    £120.00                         
                                       £0.00     £0.00           .
```

The resulting two rows is because of the GROUP BY.(rowGroup).
Date is the columnGroup.
Ideally, I would like this to be in a single row.

The query is

```
SELECT
   rates_Booking.date
   rates_Booking.amount,    
   booking.reference    

FROM
   rates_Booking
   LEFT JOIN booking ON booking.reference = rates_Booking.bookingReference                                                                  

   LEFT JOIN unit ON booking.apartment = unit.unit

   LEFT JOIN property ON property.property = unit.property

 WHERE
   rates_Booking.date BETWEEN $P{startDate} AND $P{endDate} 

   AND  $X{IN,property.property,buildings}
   AND  $X{IN,property.area,location}
   AND  $X{IN, unit.unit, unit}

UNION


   SELECT
    rates_Calendar.date
    0.00 as amount,
    '' as reference     

FROM
    rates_Calendar,unit


    LEFT JOIN property ON property.property = unit.property
    LEFT JOIN regions ON regions.region = property.area

    # unit to apartments
    LEFT JOIN apartments ON (apartments.unit = unit.unit)
    LEFT JOIN apartmentTypes ON (apartmentTypes.id = apartments.apartmentTypeId)


WHERE
    rates_Calendar.date BETWEEN $P{startDate} AND $P{endDate}
    AND rates_Calendar.date NOT IN (
                                       SELECT   
                                          rates_Booking.date
                                       FROM                                                                           
                                          rates_Booking                                                                             
                                          LEFT JOIN booking ON booking.reference =   rates_Booking.bookingReference                                 
                                          LEFT JOIN unit ON booking.apartment = unit.unit
                                          LEFT JOIN property ON property.property = unit.property                                                                               

                                          LEFT JOIN apartments ON (apartments.unit =  unit.unit)                                                                                                                         
                                          LEFT JOIN apartmentTypes ON (apartmentTypes.id = apartments.apartmentTypeId)

                                        WHERE                                                                            
                                           rates_Booking.date BETWEEN $P{startDate} AND $P{endDate}                                                                                                                                                         
                                           AND  $X{IN, unit.unit, unit}                                                                                                 
                                           AND  $X{IN, apartmentTypes.id,apartmentType}

                                        GROUP BY

                                           rates_Booking.date



                                            )                                                                                        



    AND $X{IN,property.property,buildings}
    AND $X{IN,property.area,location}
    AND $X{IN, unit.unit, unit}
```

Also, can someone suggest so that it does not need a UNION.
I know using the subquery will not result in optimal performance.
But having the WHERE conditions in the ON clauses in JOINS does not help.

Comment: I have changed the main post and included the query now.

Comment: As I've said, this is not the ideal way. I changed this to use the subquery inside a LEFT JOIN which means that I've eliminated the need to use UNION.

Comment: but the question still remains.. is there a way I can get it into a single row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT DATE, SUM(AMOUNT)
 FROM (first query UNION second query)
 GROUP BY DATE
 ORDER BY DATE
```

Comment: As an aside, if you only want one query, I do something like this in Oracle using a partitioned outer join (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/outerjoin-097144.html). Maybe someone who is more familiar with MySQL knows if this is possible with MySQL too?

Comment: Thanks for that Lisa. I had done that. But have removed the UNION resulting in a more efficient query.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding the 0.00 values in the query you could also add them in the crosstab detail field modifying the field expression for the field in the Detail/Detail section:

`$V{amountMeasure} == null ? 0.00 : $V{amountMeasure}`

assuming that `$V{amountMeasure}` is the generated name of the measure based on the amount field.